# Two scrollbars problems?

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, position

Following up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297211/jquery-how-can-i-reset-the-document-scrollbar-when-i-append-a-layer-over-the-doc), I made a test, but I still got a bit of problem - the page has two scroll bars when you click to display the image.

I don't need the background scrollbar when the image is being displayed, I only need the scrollbar on the image container.

How can I hide the background scrollbar without making the page jumpy?

the css,

```
#container-image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index:100;
}
```

the html,

```
<p>Please scroll down until you see the click button</p>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<a href="#" class="get-photo">click</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="container-image" style="display:none">
    <ul id="items-image">
        <li><img src="winnie-the-pooh-2011-4.jpg"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.get-photo').click(function(){

            var object = $(this);
            var object_path = object.attr('href');
            var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
            //alert(object_path);
            $('#container-image').show();
            return false;
        });

    });
```

Here is the test [page](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/position.fixed/).

**EDIT:**

Just managed to hide the `body` scrollbar and it works on all browsers accept IE8 - how can I fix IE??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.get-photo').click(function(){
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            var object = $(this);
            var object_path = object.attr('href');
            var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
            var height_document = $(document).height();
            //alert(object_path);

            $('#background-photo').css({

                height:height_document + 'px',
                display:'block'

            });

            $('#container-image').show();
            return false;
        });

        $('#items-image img').click(function(){

            var object = $(this);
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
            $('#container-image').hide();
            $('#background-photo').hide();
            return false;
        });

    });
```

**EDIT:**

Fixed IE8:

```
$('body,html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Your sample page has [193 validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flauthiamkok.net%2Fdump%2Fposition.fixed%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Take care of those and your chances of cross-browser consistency increases.  Also consider using margins or other CSS positioning instead of a million `<br/>`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `overflow: hidden` on the body while the image is being displayed, to hide the scrollbars:

```
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Just managed to hide the body scrollbar and it works on all browsers accept IE8 - how can I fix IE? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just removed in Firebug following styles:

```
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

and I can see the background without scroll. Try it.

But in this case if the background image bigger than visible browser window - you never will be able to see the whole image because of `position:fixed`