# Problem with document body's overflow to hidden

Tags: jquery, css, dom, append, margin

After getting the right answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299495/two-scrollbars-problems), I am having another problem - adding `margin:0em auto;` to my page will cause the page 'jumpy'

```
.align-center-public {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0em auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

<div id="container">

    <div class="align-center-public">

        <p style="width:800px; text-align:center; border:1px solid #000;"><a href="#">Please scroll down until you see the click button</a></p>
        <p><img src="winnie-the-pooh-2011-9.jpg" alt="test"/></p>
        <p><img src="winnie-the-pooh-2011-9.jpg" alt="test"/></p>
        <p><img src="winnie-the-pooh-2011-9.jpg" alt="test"/></p>
        <div><a href="#" class="get-photo">click here</a></div>
        <p><img src="winnie-the-pooh-2011-9.jpg" alt="test"/></p>

    </div>

</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Here is the [link](http://lauthiamkok.net/dump/position.fixed/) again.

Comment: "to my page will cause the page 'jumpy'" what do you mean with that?

Comment: He means when you click the link to get the overlay box, the background content shifts to the right about 5px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9) 
    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');

$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden').css('padding-right','17px');
```

And:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 9) 
    $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');

$('body').css('overflow', 'auto').css('padding-right', 0);
```

And now I'm noticing that this apparently is all you need.

http://jfcoder.com/test/pooh.html

To keep the page from correcting when the scrollbars disappear, you need to pad the `BODY` appropriately. This is more than likely a different value for each browser. The above I have tested in FF6, IE8/9 and Chrome latest only.

Comment: This brings 2 scrollbars on the page.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice until just now.

Comment: Note, I've updated my post since @ShankarSangoli pointed out the scrollbar problem.

Comment: thanks Jared! I just tested it on IE8 and it has the same problem - can check the page on IE8 please...? other browsers (and IE9) work fine.

Comment: That's because you'll need to apply the same logic to all browsers. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try a javascript pure... best 'body', not try use 'html' is bug.

```
<script>
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are changing the `body` overflow `hidden` to `auto` on clicing `click here` link. Is it required to be changed?

Comment: yes I need to change  `body`'s overflow to `hidden` otherwise I will have this problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299495/two-scrollbars-problems

Answer (score 0):

It seems, too, that the images are being redisplayed when the viewport shrinks horizontally, but only after the viewport width narrows to within some set width. That's why you are getting the flash. How about putting some more borders around the images so you can get an idea what that width is?

Also: you don't have to put the images in <p>s -- there might be some interaction between paragraph and image processing in the browser. You might want to remove the <p>s and see what happens.